# evaluate the limit when x goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Evaluate $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} (x^3+6x^2+1)^{\frac13}-(x^2}+x+1)^{\frac12}$

I tried writing it as $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3+6x^2+1}{(x^3+6x^2+1)^{\frac23}}-\frac{x^2+x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^{\frac12}}$$ but I do not know how to continue from this point.

I really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: rewrite as$$\lim_{x\to\infty}((x^3+6x^2+1)^{1/3}-x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}((x^2+x+1)^{1/2}-x)$$then use$$a-b=\frac{a^n-b^n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-k}}$$to evaluate each limit.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Let $t=\frac{1}{x}$. Then

$$(x^3+6x^2+1)^{\frac13}-(x^2+x+1)^{\frac12}
=
\frac{(t^3+6t+1)^{\frac13}-(t^2+t+1)^{\frac12}}{t} = \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0} 
$$

where $f(t)=(t^3+6t+1)^{\frac13}-(t^2+t+1)^{\frac12}$. Therefore, if it exists, the limit you are looking for is equal to $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$, the limit exists and is equal to $f'(0)$.

Using Taylor series, $f(t)=0+\frac{3}{2}t+...$, so $f'(0)=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me

Comment: Looks way overkill. Also how do you compute the Taylor series of $f$?

Comment: @Adayah: you only need a few terms of the Taylor series, so it is quite easy (it is similar to what Sine of the Time did). You can also compute the derivative of $f$ using usual formulas if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x^3+6x^2+1)^{\frac13}-(x^2+x+1)^{\frac12}$$
Using $(1+t)^a\sim1+at $ as $t\to0$, you have:
$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+6x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=x\sqrt[3]{1+6/x+1/x^3}-x\sqrt{1+1/x+1/x^2}\sim \\ x(1+2/x)-x(1+1/2x)=2-1/2=3/2$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\sim$ ?

Comment: @Adayah asymptotic equivalence

Comment: If you mean $f \sim g \iff \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$, then the argument is incorrect for multiple reasons. A typical example of how this fails: $(x+1) - x \sim x - x = 0$, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x+1) - x = 0$.

Comment: @Adayah (x+1)-x =1 so it doesn't make sense saying $\sim 0$

Comment: It doesn't, right? But I only followed the same rules that you did.

How do you rigorously justify this? $$x \sqrt[3]{1+6/x+1/x^3} - x \sqrt{1+1/x+1/x^2} \sim x(1+2/x) - x(1+1/2x)$$

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{x^3+6x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=x(1+2/x)-x(1+1/2x)+o(1/x)$ so they have the same behaviour @Adayah

Comment: You only invoked a more powerful equality that again needs a justification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149658/discussion-between-sine-of-the-time-and-adayah).